# How do I know how long will an algorithm (e.g. k-means) take to run?

Tags: performance, algorithm, k-means

For example, I'm running the k-means algorithm on 1 million data points.  Each point is 128-dimensional, and I want 1000 clusters. Wikipedia tells me that its complexity is n^(dk+1)log(n), where d is the number of dimensions, k number of clusters and n number of instances. 
Knowing that, how can I get an estimate of how long it will run on my 8-Gb RAM, 2.6GHz Intel Core i5 MacBook Pro?  What is the best way to calculate this estimate? Is there a way to calculate it theoretically or should I do a few experiments on smaller sets and see how long it takes?
I would really like to have rough estimate before I spend hours or days without knowing when it might stop.
Thanks so much for your help! I really appreciate it :).

Ps. I'm using pythons' scipy kmeans

Comment: `1M^128k` is about `10^768000`. Compare to age of universe `<10^27` nanoseconds. Clearly finding optimal solution is out of reach. You have to settle for some approximation.

Comment: scipy is a practical library and it probably doesn't use algorithm with cited complexity. In such a case experimentation is probably way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Do some experiments. k-means is popular only because it usually runs much, much faster than that asymptotic bound would suggest.

Answer (score 0):

There is so much machine-related and algorithm-related specifics which is hidden in the big-O constant that it won't be possible to estimate it (for your machine and your SciPy) theoretically.

However nothing will prevent you from finding the constant experimentally - as you said: "do a few experiments on smaller sets".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ok, I will do some experiments. However, I would like to be able to get a VERY ROUGH estimate, not just for the kmeans algorithm but for any algorithm for which I know the complexity. Can I say that since my processor can perform 2.6e9 cycles per second (assuming conservatively 1 operation per cycle), that my algorithm will take big-O divided by 2.6e9?  Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: One operation per cycle - is too optimistic. Look at "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycles_per_instruction"... Also memory accesses - there is a multilevel cache (L1/L2/L3) which is fast, but access to main memory might take hundreds of cycles.